# Compare row wise value change in Oracle using SQl only

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table like this ,

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Quarter`**</kbd>   <kbd>**`Risk`**</kbd>          
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q0`</kbd>        <kbd>`2`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q1`</kbd>        <kbd>`3`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q2`</kbd>        <kbd>`1`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q3`</kbd>        <kbd>`1`</kbd>             
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q4`</kbd>        <kbd>`2`</kbd>

`1 means Lower Risk and 3 means Higher Risk` . And `Q0 means 4th Quarter of previous year` .

I want a output like this :

<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd>        <kbd>**`Quarter`**</kbd>   <kbd>**`Risk`**</kbd>          <kbd>**`Status`**</kbd>    
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q0`</kbd>        <kbd>`2`</kbd>             <kbd>`null`</kbd>      
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q1`</kbd>        <kbd>`3`</kbd>             <kbd>`Upgraded`</kbd>  
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q2`</kbd>        <kbd>`1`</kbd>             <kbd>`Downgraded`</kbd>
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q3`</kbd>        <kbd>`1`</kbd>             <kbd>`No Change`</kbd> 
<kbd>`00001`</kbd>     <kbd>`Q4`</kbd>        <kbd>`2`</kbd>             <kbd>`Upgraded`</kbd>

If the **Risk** is greater than that of its previous quarter then it is **Upgraded** and otherwise **Downgraded** . If the value remains same then **No Change**.

> **I want to achieve this using only SQL in Oracle 10G. I cannot use
>   PL/SQL**.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Show us your query attempt, we would appreciate it.

Comment: Please show what you have attempted and what is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `lag()` :

```
select t.*,
       (case when Risk > prev_rsk
             then 'Upgraded'
             when Risk < prev_rsk
             then 'Downgraded'
             when Risk = prev_rsk
             then 'No Change'
        end) as Status
from (select t.*,
             lag(Risk) over (partition by id order by Quarter) as prev_rsk
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 3):

The same can be achieved using lag function which is available in Oracle 10g.

```
select id
      ,quarter
      ,risk
      ,case when risk - lag(risk) over(order by quarter) <0 then 
                 'Downgraded'
            when risk - lag(risk) over(order by quarter) =0 then 
                 'No change'
            when risk - lag(risk) over(order by quarter) >0 then 
                 'Upgraded'
       end as status 
  from table
```